# Is there a shortcut for "Auto Shrink" on GIMP?

Tags: gimp, shortcuts

In order to Auto Shrink a selection, I find the toolbar window (<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) and push the "Auto Shrink" button.

I do this quite often and would like to know if there's a shortcut built in to GIMP.  If not, is there a way to make one specifically for this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found no way to do this. Dynamic Keyboard Shortcuts do not work with the Auto Shrink button. And there is not an entry for it in the Configure Keyboard Shortcuts menu.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way of doing this? In the sense of "stop searching everybody" I know enough about GIMP to be sure this cannot be done? Or is your answer just literally that you have not found a way in the sense of "mine is not really an answer"? Not a criticism, just surprised and even more that yours got the tick.

Comment: I have not found a way within the current version of GIMP. The only reason I provided a "non answer" answer is because I don't have enough rep to simply comment (pretty backwards system allowing one to start a new entry but not comment on an existing one). I came here searching for an answer and the one provided is completely false. I wanted to save others the trouble of wondering why they couldn't get dynamic shortcuts to work. There is probably a way to do it by changing the source code, but this is beyond me. Maybe if enough of us submit a feature request we can see it in the next update.

Answer (score 2):

All shortcuts in GIMP are easily customizable. The existing, defaut, shortcuts are visible on the right side of each menu entry. To create others, you just go to `edit->preferences->interface->shortcuts`  - which personally I don't like, as it takes too long to set up each wanted shortcut. The other way is to go to `Edit->Preferences->Interface` and enable the `Use Dynamic Keyboard Shortcuts` option.

From there on, just highlight any meny option, by hovering the pointer to it, and press the desired shrotcut for that option (For example `ctrl`+ `a`, or the any number from `0` to `9`). That is it - the shortcut is configured.

Comment: Auto Shrink isn't a menu command, though, it is a button in the tool options. Now there are some mappable generic tool options (i.e. they are anonymously numbered), but I'm not sure if this button is among one of them.